# Split after regex max without losing delimeter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to transform a string like:
`hello!world.what?up` into `["hello!", "world.", "what?", "up"]`

`.split(/[?=<\.\?\!>]+/)` is close to what I'm after, which returns:

`["hello", "world", "what", "up"]`

`.split(/(?=[\?\!\.])/)` is a bit closer yet, which returns:

`["hello", "!world", ".what", "?up"]`

This does the trick, but it's not pretty:

`.split(/(?=[\?\!\.])/).map((s, idx, arr) => { (idx > 0) s = s.slice(1); return idx < arr.length - 1 ? s + arr[idx+1][0] : s }).filter(s => s)`

How would I rephrase this to achieve the desired output?

Edit: Updated question.

Comment: Wouldn't removing the `?` from the list in the second example give you the desired output (`/(?=[\!\.])/`) ?

Comment: I'd like to use a `?` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the real requirement but to accomplish what you want you could use `.match` instead of `.split`.

```js
const items =
  'hello!world.what?'.match(/\w+\W/g);

console.log(items);
```

[image]

---

**update after comment**

You could add a group for any character you want to use as the terminator for each part.

```js
const items =
  'hello!world.what?'.match(/\w+[!.?]/g);

console.log(items);
```

[image]

---

**additional update**

the previous solution would only select alphanumeric chars before the `!.?` 
If you want to match any char except the delimiters then use

```js
const items =
  'hello!world.what?up'.match(/[^!.?]+([!.?]|$)/g);

console.log(items);
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close, but I only want to split on those 3 characters. (And maybe semicolons.)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help! `'hello!world.what?up'.match(/\w+[!.?]/g)` misses the tail of the string if it doesn't end with punctuation -- how might I match these as well?

Comment: @iRyanBell was just adding a more generic way and added support for an un-terminated last part as well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be first to use `replace()` for add a token after each searched character, then you can split by this token.

```js
let input = "hello!world.what?";

const customSplit = (str) =>
{
    let token = "#";
    return str.replace(/[!.?]/g, (match) => match + "#")
        .split(token)
        .filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(customSplit(input));
```